# Flutter: DraggableScrollableActuator no funciona

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy haciendo una app con un mapa con varios marcadores.

Cuando pulsas un marcador la app despliega un DraggableScrollableSheet mediante un AnimationController. Lo ideal sería que al pulsar un marcador nuevo, se abrirera el DraggableScrollSheet con los valores iniciales, es decir, que se resetearan los valores.

Para eso, utilizo el método reset de DraggableScrollableActuator en la propiedad onTap del marcador, pero no funciona.

Lo curioso de todo esto es que si lo hago desde la propiedad onPressed de un botón (que he creado para hacer este experimento), sí que funciona. No entiendo que ocurre.

**El código del DraggableScrollableSheet:**

```
NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
            child: DraggableScrollableActuator(
              child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                builder: (BuildContext draggableContext,ScrollController controller) {
                  _draggableContext = draggableContext;

                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 300,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                initialChildSize: 0.25,
                maxChildSize: 1,
                minChildSize: 0.05,
                expand: true,
              ),
            ),
            onNotification: (notificacion) {  
              return true;
            },
          )
```

**El código de los marcadores:**

```
Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(_parades[i].idParada.toString()),
        position:LatLng(_parades[i].parada.latitud, _parades[i].parada.longitud),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: _parades[i].parada.descParada),
        icon: defaultMarkerIcon,
        onTap: (){
          if (markerFlag != i) {
            setState(() {
              if (markerFlag != null) {
                _allMarkers[markerFlag] = _allMarkers[markerFlag]
                    .copyWith(iconParam: defaultMarkerIcon);
              }
              _allMarkers[i] = _allMarkers[i].copyWith(iconParam: selectedMarkerIcon);
              markerFlag = i;
            });
          }

          _animationController.reset();
          DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(_draggableContext);
          _animationController.forward();              

        },
      )
```

**Botón donde funciona el reset:**

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _animationController.reset();
          DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(_draggableContext);
          _animationController.forward();
        },
      )
```

Comment: prueba quitando la condición if dentro del ontap del marker y revisa si funciona

Comment: Esa condición no afecta para nada al reset, en principio. Ya que está fuera de la condición y además esa condición funciona perfectamente. De todas formas da igual, me rendí con el DraggableScrollableSheet e implementé el package SlidingUpPanel, que es 100 veces mejor.

Comment: Lo digo porque tiene un setState

Comment: En qué afecta que haya un setState? Lo pregunto porque soy novato en Flutter.

Comment: Podría ser que està interviniendo con la animación del reset, por eso puedes probar quitandole la condicion con el setState

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y tienes razón. Está interfiriendo. Sin el condicional el reset funciona. Pero como puedo tener las dos cosas? Ese condicional es imprescindible para cambiar el icono del marcador seleccionado...

Comment: Puedes subscribirte al canal de youtube que tengo con un amigo, donde hablamos de Dart y Flutter : https://youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que causa el problema es que estás usando `setState` antes de llamar al `reset` , al usar `setState` internamente marcas el estado del widget como dirty para que vuelva a ser pintado.

Y como inmediatamente llamas a `DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(_draggableContext);` este es ignorado porque el widget está siendo repintado.

Para solucionarlo podrías usar un pequeño delay con el método delayed:

```dart
onTap: () async {
          if (markerFlag != i) {
            setState(() {
              if (markerFlag != null) {
                _allMarkers[markerFlag] = _allMarkers[markerFlag]
                    .copyWith(iconParam: defaultMarkerIcon);
              }
              _allMarkers[i] = _allMarkers[i].copyWith(iconParam: selectedMarkerIcon);
              markerFlag = i;
            });
          }
           await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
          _animationController.reset();
          DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(_draggableContext);
          _animationController.forward();              

        },
```